# How can I observe memory bandwidth?

Tags: linux, memory, embedded, benchmark

I have an embedded Linux ARM system that is showing significantly less throughput than expected on both Ethernet and USB. I suspect the memory may be contributing. Is there a way to observe the memory bandwidth that is consumed while running a throughput test on the Ethernet or USB?

Comment: What platform? The best method may be architecture-specific.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a memory [bandwidth benchmark](http://zsmith.co/bandwidth.html) available in open source. It works for Intel & ARM under Linux or Windows Mobile CE.

It will give you raw performance for your memory as well as system performance with memory. But it won't give you a real-time bandwidth, so I don't know if it's a good answer to your question.

There's also a [memtop](https://github.com/MartinThoma/memtop) tool out there, but it's more about [usage](http://virtualthreads.blogspot.com/2006/02/understanding-memory-usage-on-linux.html) than bandwidth. [Perf tool](http://anton.ozlabs.org/blog/2009/09/04/using-performance-counters-for-linux/) can be handy in order to detect page fault.

Comment: "The project has migrated to [https://github.com/MartinThoma/memtop](https://github.com/MartinThoma/memtop)."

Answer (score 8):

In Debian and derivatives like Ubuntu you can run the "mbw" command

> $ sudo apt-get install mbw

Then execute a 2GB memory test (assuming you have enough RAM for that without affecting other applications and swapping)...

> $ mbw 2048